# Grafana Container does not pick up changes from env file even after updated compose file and updated values in inspect command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grafana

### System Information

```sh
docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.5.0
```

### Design

I am using a `Makefile` that uses the multiple compose file logic using the `-f` flag in `docker compose` alongside the `config` command to build a `docker-compose.yml`. The `Makefile` can build the compose file, run it as well as bring it down and remove the file

#### Structure

```sh
├── conf
│   ├── grafana
│   │   ├── config
│   │   │   └── grafana.ini
|   |   |-- .env
├── docker-compose.base.yml
├── services
│   ├── docker-compose.grafana.yml
```

The `conf` directory has all the `.env` file where I pass the necessary admin credentials for Grafana

**`conf/grafana/.env`**

```
## Grafana Admin Credentials
GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=admin
GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=supersecretpass
```

**`docker-compose.base.yml`**

```yaml
networks:
  internal:

services:
  grafana:
     env_file:
       - ./conf/grafana/.env
     volumes:
       - grafana:/var/lib/grafana
       - ./conf/grafana/config:/usr/local/etc/grafana
```

**`services/docker-compose.grafana.yml`**

```yaml
services:
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:8.4.5
    container_name: my-grafana
    environment:
      - GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=/grafana
      - GF_SERVER_SERVE_FROM_SUB_PATH=true
      - GF_PATHS_CONFIG=/usr/local/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "1m"
    networks:
      - internal
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    security_opt:
      - "no-new-privileges:true"
    volumes:
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
```

**`Makefile`**

```
.PHONY: help build compose clean down run
.SILENT: help

SERVICES_DIR=services
COMPOSE_FILES:=-f docker-compose.base.yml

# STEP: 1 Add the service name here
define OPTIONS
    - grafana -
endef
export OPTIONS

ARGS=$(wordlist 2, $(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),$(MAKECMDGOALS))
$(eval $(ARGS):;@:)



ifeq (grafana, $(filter grafana,$(ARGS)))
    COMPOSE_FILES:=$(COMPOSE_FILES) -f $(SERVICES_DIR)/docker-compose.grafana.yml
endif

SERVICES:=$(filter-out ${OPTIONS},$(ARGS))

.PHONY: $(OPTIONS)

help:
    echo "refer to the README.md file"

build:
    make compose grafana

compose:
    docker compose $(COMPOSE_FILES) config > docker-compose.yml

clean:down
    rm -rf ./docker-compose.yml

down:
    docker compose down

run:build
    docker compose up -d $(SERVICES)
```

### Problem Reproduction

1. I run the following:

   ```
    make run
   ```

   which will build the `docker-compose.yml` file in the root using the `docker compose config` command and using the `-f services/docker-compose.grafana.yml` command with the base file.
2. Once the container is up and reachable on `localhost:3000` I check by entering the password and it works
3. Now I change the password in the `conf/grafana/.env` to `supersecretpass2` and run the `make run` again

   This actually rewrites the `docker-compose.yml` file with the newly updated environment variables for `grafana` service and re-runs the `docker compose up` command again which should pick up the new configuration i.e., new password.

### Problem

Even though the `docker-compose.yml` is updated and the CLI states that the container is recreated and restarted, upon entering the new password the Grafana UI does not pick up the adapted environment variable

#### Inspection

upon doing

```sh
docker inspect my-grafana
```

I can clearly see the

```json
  "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=supersecretpass2",
                "GF_SERVER_SERVE_FROM_SUB_PATH=true",
                "GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=admin",
                "GF_PATHS_CONFIG=/usr/local/etc/grafana/grafana.ini",
                "GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=/grafana",
                "PATH=/usr/share/grafana/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "GF_PATHS_DATA=/var/lib/grafana",
                "GF_PATHS_HOME=/usr/share/grafana",
                "GF_PATHS_LOGS=/var/log/grafana",
                "GF_PATHS_PLUGINS=/var/lib/grafana/plugins",
                "GF_PATHS_PROVISIONING=/etc/grafana/provisioning"
            ],
```

by executing:

```sh
docker compose exec -it grafana /bin/bash env
```

I can see that the updated env var of the password is passed into the container, however Grafana does not pick this changes up.

the UI mentions the password is invalid, but accepts the original password.

### Repo for Bug Reproduction

In order to reproduce this bug I have the following [repo](https://github.com/shantanoo-desai/compose-v2-env-vars-problem)

Comment: Have you actually changed anything in the `docker-compose.yml` file, or are you rewriting it with identical contents and a pointer to the modified `.env` file?  If the `docker-compose.yml` file doesn't have any substantive changes, Compose won't recreate the container.

Comment: @DavidMaze I do since the `base` file uses the `env_file` the env vars get resolved to their respective values in the _re-generated_ compose file. This should imply there is a change there and it should pick it up. Also the the feedback from the compose CLI mentions that it does recreate the container.

Comment: @DavidMaze I found out that upon further investigation, the problem lies in the grafana container as opposed to compose v2